# Typescript generics: union of generic types that extend string

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that takes one parameter of type: `Options`. Type `Options` contains a couple of properties (`obj1` and `obj2`) that are basically plain old js objects and an `item` property whose value should be a key of `obj1` or a key of `obj2`. Is it possible to achieve this in typescript? Here's what I tried:

```
declare function f<t1 extends string = never, t2 extends string = never>(opts?: Options<t1, t2>): void;

export interface Options<t1 extends string = never, t2 extends string = never> {
    obj1: {[K in t1]: any}
    obj2: {[K in t2]: any}
    item: t1 | t2;
}

// this should work but doesn't
f({
    obj1: {
        red: null,
        green: null
    },
    obj2: {
        black: null,
        white: null
    },
    item: 'white'
});
```

Basically I was hoping that type argument `t1` would resolve to `red | green` and `t2` to `black | white` so that `t1 | t2` would resolve to `red | green | black | white`. Instead what happens seems to be that `t1 | t2` is first resolved to `white`, then both `t1` and `t2` are inferred to be `white` as well.  Any hint?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4AVARnhAA8MRVgBneAJXBxmALoxi1QHMAaeFFQBPAHyCiAJnJUa9JizYcuPAUNFixACgBQ8eDgAOGOgH4AXPADe+g4YBGAKxJXSAbjsGczqW6me9vBY1AC2VgDWICI4iPCk8AA+8FExcdKB8AC+ugCUVgBuOFjAnroA9OXwGAAWWAx0NTjIEMDwAO6sEfAOyBjwwDggdKgA5Bi6iNq23s6uNl7wvHA0VqgtEPyLcMBrG1sGWQeOTn4LQQ7QYBF7EJuL7XXUt-eHxyEg4fCjjx+jW1lcp4gA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame unfortunately not. In the question I simplified my case to make it clearer.

Comment: @wonderflame the reality is closer to [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIB4MBGeEADwxFWAGd5aMYtUBzeAXnlRADcQYAGngYATGUrU6DJi3Zce-GAD4AFDgAOGWgH4AXPADyW3KlpFiwscoCUB3jizAA3AChXFDThgZ4LKjCIUGAIxth45iQSVDT0jMxsnNx8AlbiFDHS8XJJigLK0VL0Yaa0AEJQtCAWBQDervCN8DgARgBWoga1ANoA0n74YgC6BlCoAJ4Avg1NWFQAtgZRAD4iom7TrgD0W-AAkvBgYwDkvmAAFmOsCBjnWPSgkLBQ4aiuj9BwAwFBIUYmEQqVSIhViMgS8mSSjqM0arTaxC6fQGIhG8DGU1cmx2IjucXOOGQEGA8AA7t4ANbwFrIXzAHAgWioU6uRCqepNZrtRHwDmcppwYAGVBEiCCWH81hwajC0USybiznwzq8iWclrQMAU2UQMVqpqku5UHUQeWK2YLAzHQ1zEDHLE2NxAA).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the item attribute generic too, this way instead of it being `t1|t2` and forcing typescript to guess that t1|t2 = "white", you can tell it that item is merely taking a value from t1|t2

```js
// ItemKey added here
declare function f<t1 extends string = never, t2 extends string = never, ItemKey extends t1|t2=never>(opts?: Options<t1, t2, ItemKey>): void;

// ItemKey also added here
export interface Options<t1 extends string = never, t2 extends string = never, ItemKey extends t1|t2 = never> extends OptionsBase<t1> {
    obj2: {[K in t2]: any}
    item: ItemKey;
}

// I can't change this declaration
declare interface OptionsBase<t extends string = never> {
    obj1: {[K in t]: any}
}

// Now f's generic arguments are <"red" | "green", "black" | "white", "white">
f({
    obj1: {
        red: null,
        green: null
    },
    obj2: {
        black: null,
        white: null
    },
    item: 'white'
});
```